# How to get last duplicate from above the Name value, to get name values from next colum to get in array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, multidimensional-array, google-sheets-formula

**Current Issue:**

Hey everyone, appreciate any help here as I'm still beginning my journey in coding.

I'm trying to see if I can make a script that will:

Look for previous duplicated value (in same column A), and gets it value in array to use the formula for calculating distance of dead head. i found formula that work for array in same raw, but Now I am stuck with getting array from column for last duplicated value above the value.

Please can anyone will help to get resolvance of an array formula for the column.

for example I am looking for duplicate from name column to get destination column value and send it to the formula in array
target that i am looking for is array origin and destination  (E2:F)

I have not find array formula for the column to get preivous duplicate

[example that i try to get responce](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KMt5fngmyB3ESuz34q5Aq0IWRmCY1XPPv48HVuSuDUE/edit?usp=sharing)

[in the script i have found that highlights duplicates](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KMt5fngmyB3ESuz34q5Aq0IWRmCY1XPPv48HVuSuDUE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @rockinfreakshow Hi, i have uploaded the sheet the response in the sheet looking to be E2:F that is just a demo that i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ;map(A2:A;lambda(Σ;countif(A2:Σ;Σ)));
     map(A2:A;B2:B;Σ;lambda(a;b;Λ;if(Λ>1;{filter(C2:C;A2:A=a;Σ=Λ-1)\b};))))
```

[image]

Comment: i have the google sheet formula to get two values but here i am using google distance matrix , so if the value higher than 50 request it will stop getting request. so here i need to get script for calculating only array that has been inputted below the list, so each time formula will run for each array again